# \bfseries equivalent for italics?

Tags: macros, italic

Is there an equivalent to the command `\bfseries` that makes the text italic? In the context I plan to use it `\textit{ }` does not work and yelds an error: `Runaway argument? {   ! Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete. <to be read again> \par`. I had the same problem with bold text, but changing from `\textbf{ }` to `\bfseries` worked fine.

Comment: `\itshape`.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the switch is named : `\itshape`

source: http://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-italics.html

Answer (score 3):

The name of the command is `\itshape`:

```
\begingroup
\itshape
<text goes here>
\endgroup
```

or: `{\itshape <text goes here> }`.